# how can I logout from keycloak server through my application which is in php?

Tags: php, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

Greeting from my side..

Actually I have implemented SSO of Keycloak in my php app using the following library
"**Keycloak Provider for OAuth 2.0 Client**".

link :- https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak

And I have achieve the login fuctionality successfully using keycloak authentication and enter in my app using keycloak credentials. Now the problem is that how can i logout or destroy my session in keycloak server through my app i.e. when user click on the logout button ?
I am stuck here . Can anyone help me or guide me ?

Comment: Look at the issue there : https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak/issues/37. In theory, the oauth2 provider has a logout endpoint. The logout page of the client need to call this endpoint after logged out the user.

Comment: but I didn't understand that how to use this endpoint

Comment: The library has a method. It's seems to be something like : $provider->getLogoutUrl();

Comment: what parameters I need to pass ?

Comment: Parameters are not required. I don't know this library to give the list of accepted parameters and their role